# Base change and ordinals

Tags: set-theory, ordinals

> **Problem.** Define the operation *base change from $k$ to $m$*: to make the operation for natural number $n$ we should write $n$ in the base-$k$ numeral system and read this in the base-$m$ numeral system.
>
> Let $n$ be a natural number. Make for $n$ base change from $2$ to $3$, then subtract $1$, then change base from $3$ to $4$, then subtract $1$ and so on.
>
> Prove that we'll get zero after finitely many steps.

For example, for $n=4$ the sequence is
$$9,8,10,9,11,10,12,11,12,11,12,11,12,11,12,11,12,11,\\
12,11,11,10,10,9,9,8,8,7,7,6,6,5,5,4,4,3,3,2,2,1,1,0.$$

For $n=6$ the sequence contain 762 terms.

The problem has elementary proofs, but it's from a book on Set Theory and authors says that it has a solution using ordinals: change all bases to $\omega$ and get decreasing sequence of ordinals.

I can't understand this hint.

Comment: The "standard proof" I know constructs a strictly decreasing parallel series of ordinals by substituting every $n$ in your presentation with $\omega$. At each step your parallel series is greater or equal to your original series, but as it is strictly increasing and the ordinals are well ordered it has to go to zero eventually, so that your original series has to go to zero. By the way: This is known as [Goodstein's theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Goodstein%27s_theorem).

Comment: I think you meant strictly **decreasing**.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott: The theorem is perfectly true for ordinary base-$k$ notation. It is just that in Goodstein's theorem the exponents are also recursively expressed in base-$k$ so as to obtain an even wilder statement (one that cannot be proved in PA, I think).

Comment: My sequence is not a Goodstein's sequence, because I change *only* base, but in a Goodstein's sequence we work with so called *hereditary* base-$k$ notation and change *all* $k$ to $k+1$. My sequence follow to zero much faster.

Comment: Yes, there is a hierarchy of stronger and stronger "Goodstein theorems". In your case, we replace $2^a+2^b+\dots$ with $3^a+3^b+\dots$, etc. The next case applies the change of base to $a,b,\dots$ as well. For the next case, you write $a=2^\alpha+2^\beta+\dots$, same for $b$, etc, and apply the change of base also to $\alpha,\beta,\dots$. Etc. The usual "Goodstein theorem" is in a sense the limit of this process. Each new level we go up, the corresponding theorem requires an extra instance of induction to be provable (over the base theory that is Peano arithmetic without the induction schema).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Suppose at the base $n$ stage you have the representation $a_ka_{k-1}\dots a_1a_0$, representing

$$g_n=a_kn^k+a_{k-1}n^{k-1}+\ldots+a_1n+a_0\;,$$

where $a_0,\dots,a_k\in\{0,\dots,n-1\}$, and $a_k\ne 0$. Let

$$\hat g_n=\omega^k\cdot a_k+\omega^{k-1}\cdot a_{k-1}+\ldots+\omega\cdot a_1+a_0\;,$$

where the arithmetic is all ordinal arithmetic. The change of base from $n$ to $n+1$ changes the interpretation of $a_ka_{k-1}\dots a_1a_0$ to

$$a_k(n+1)^k+a_{k-1}n^{k-1}+\ldots+a_1(n+1)+a_0\;.\tag{1}$$

If $a_0\ne 0$, subtracting $1$ yields

$$g_{n+1}=a_k(n+1)^k+a_{k-1}n^{k-1}+\ldots+a_1(n+1)+(a_0-1)\;,$$

and

$$\hat g_{n+1}=\omega^k\cdot a_k+\omega^{k-1}\cdot a_{k-1}+\ldots+\omega\cdot a_1+(a_0-1)<\hat g_n\;.$$

In general suppose that $a_i$ is the rightmost non-zero coefficient/digit. Then subtracting $1$ from $(1)$ yields

$$g_{n+1}=a_k(n+1)^k+\ldots+(a_i-1)(n+1)^i+\underbrace{n(n+1)^{i-1}+\ldots+n(n+1)+n}_{\text{all coefficients }=n}\;,$$

and

$$\hat g_{n+1}=\omega^k\cdot a_k+\omega^{k-1}\cdot a_{k-1}+\ldots+\omega^i\cdot(a_i-1)+\underbrace{\omega^{i-1}\cdot n+\ldots\omega\cdot n+n}_{\text{all coefficients }=n}\;.$$

This is again less than $\hat g_n$, since

$$\omega^i\cdot a_i>\omega^i\cdot(a_i-1)+\underbrace{\omega^{i-1}\cdot n+\ldots\omega\cdot n+n}_{\text{all coefficients }=n}\;:$$

this follows from the (possibly more evident) fact that

$$\omega^i>\underbrace{\omega^{i-1}\cdot n+\ldots\omega\cdot n+n}_{\text{all coefficients }=n}\;,$$

since $\omega^i\cdot a_i=\omega^i\cdot(a_i-1)+\omega^i$.

Thus, the sequence of ordinals $\hat g_n$ is strictly decreasing and must terminate at $0$ in finitely many steps. But $\hat g_n=0$ if and only if $g_n=0$, so the same is true of the sequence of numbers $g_n$.